# Add string values into array list after looping through gridview rows c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a gridview with bulk update. After I make changes to the column and hit update button in the page, then this foreach loop is executed to update. Now how can I add these string values to arraylist after looping

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
        {
           string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
           string strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
           string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;     
        }
        ArrayList alList = new ArrayList();
        alList.Add(strID);
        alList.Add(strGroup);
        alList.Add(strValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

But the values of the string after looping is not getting inserted into arraylist. Van anyone help me through this.

Comment: why don't you use the debugger to step thru the list .. you will quickly see where you are not doing something correctly.. you need to define the alList for starters as a variable outside the loop that's accessible at the class level if  you plan to use it and or gain access to it somewhere else in the application ..if not still declare it outside the loop and create a List<string> object variable.. then inside the loop add the string variables to the List<T> personally you would be better off creating a Class object and storing the data there

Comment: I would also recommend that you google how to create a datatable that contains the 3 fields that you are trying to use and or create...

Comment: aint this the same question Michael asked? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29794413/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your code should be

```
var alList = new List<string>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
{
       string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
       string strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
       string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;     

       alList.Add(strID);
       alList.Add(strGroup);
       alList.Add(strValue);
}
```

Otherwise you're trying to add into list variable that is out of scope (since `strID` and others has been declared inside loop inner scope)

Note: don't use `ArrayList` it is obsolete. In your case it's better to use `List<string>` instead.

Or, if I missed your point and you need to add to list only variables from last iteration (as it can be supposed from your code) - then declare `strID` and other variables **outside** the loop, like this:

```
string strID = null, strGroup = null, strValue = null;
var alList = new List<string>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
{
       strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
       strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
       strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;     
}
alList.Add(strID);
alList.Add(strGroup);
alList.Add(strValue);
```

**Update**

Since we've clarified in comments your goal and actually you need not `List<string>` but rather `DataTable`, your code could look like:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
{
       var dro = dt.NewRow();
       dro["ID"] = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
       dro["Group"] = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
       dro["Value"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;

       dt.Rows.Add(dro);
}
```

Also note - data types of datatable columns can be any, not only strings - it depends on your actual data you want to store.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have totally 10 rows in my gridview. So you mean to say after looping thought all rows this code will add all the 10 rows into my arraylist or string? Also can you pls let me know how I can add those string values into a list since I am new to this.

Comment: @Learner see updated answer - probably I missed your original goal. So as you can see - it's up to you (and your goal) - either add all 10 strings or last one.

Comment: Gotcha! But my list doesn't contains column names, because later I need to convert the list to datatable and I am not column names.

Comment: @Learner not quite sure I've understood your correctly. Do you mean you need to store not only `(Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text` value, but also `lblID` (or maybe `strID`) as some column name? In this case other datastructure than list can be better suited. For example, `Dictionary<string, string`> if you following "second scenario" and adding values from the last row. Or maybe you'd better to use DataTable right now and not convert something to dataTable later - it is not sufficient information for me to decide what whill be better.

Comment: Yeah Its like I need to have column names for each columns in the list. Also it will be fine if we can directly put those string results into datatable.

Comment: Please suggest me some options as I have researched a lot couldn't end up with a solution.

Comment: But I still don't know (since you haven't specified it explicitly) - do yo want to add to yor new datatable values from all rows of your gridview or just last ones?

Comment: I want to add all new string values from gridview into a datatable with column names.

Comment: Pls let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "scope" (of your variables) issue.  Declare your strings before the loop.  And your arraylist....err...List holder object as well.

```
try
{

    List<string> alList = new List<string>();
string strID = string.Empty;
string strGroup =  string.Empty;
string strValue = string.Empty;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
    {
       strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
       strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
       strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;     
    }

    alList.Add(strID);
    alList.Add(strGroup);
    alList.Add(strValue);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

APPEND:

I would suggest creating a DTO (data transfer object), and populating them, and have that be the object/collection you send to the method that saves values to your database.

```
namespace MyApplication.Domain
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("ID = {ID}, GroupName = {GroupName}, Value='{Value}'")]
    public partial class MyDto
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } /* PK */
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}



    try
    {

        List<MyDto> dtoCollection = new List<MyDto>();


        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
        {
          string  strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
          string  strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
           string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;   

    MyDto newItem = new MyDto () {ID = Convert.ToInt32(strID), Group = strGroup, Value = strValue};

    dtoCollection.Add(newItem);  
        }

    int count = dtoCollection.Count;
    /* now send your dtoCollection to your BusinessLayer ... have your businesslayer validate the input data......then have the business layer call your datalayer...and use the List<MyDto> objects to update your database */

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Gotcha! But my list doesn't contains column names, because later I need to convert the list to datatable and I am not column names.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Is there a way to add these new gridview row values into datatable directly. Please suggest.

Comment: I haven't programmed in data-tables in 13 years.  i'm not saying data-tables are obsolete, but they are harder to maintain IMHO.  your presentation layer and business layer should not know anything about data-tables......your data-layer might know something about data-tables........its a much bigger topic then a single question about grabbing values from an asp.net grid should entail.

Comment: this is a decent tutorial.  http://imar.spaanjaars.com/573/aspnet-n-layered-applications-introduction-part-1